# InputStream charset issue with couchdB in java

Tags: java, json, character-encoding, couchdb, ektorp

I'm trying to parse a webservice that gives me JSON data in response. And I'm storing the JSON data in couchdb with ektorp. So I have a string that contains JSON data for instance :

```
String t = "{\"id\":2834361855,\"name\":\"Деменковa Елена\"}";
```

Then I transform the string into an InputStream to store the JSON just like that :

```
InputStream jsonInputStream = 
    new ByteArrayInputStream(t.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

db.update(String.valueOf(id),
               jsonInputStream,
               t.length(),
               null);
```

But it raises an exception :

> 400:Bad Request
>   URI: /databs/101
>   Response Body: 
>   {
>    "error" : "bad_request",
>    "reason" : "invalid_json"
>   }

And I'm pretty sure it's a charset issue because if I change the String so it does no longer contains any russian characters like :

```
String t = "{\"id\":2834361855,\"name\":\"toto\"}";
```

Then it works just fine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried a lot of things without any luck. Many thanks for the help I'm really stuck.

Comment: Are you able to sniff the data that is actually getting sent to CouchDB?  For example, using [eclipse tcp monitor](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-monitor-http-communication-in-eclipse.html) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed my strategy, I'm storing the data as object rather than with an inputstream. It's not perfect but it's working for my purpose